# node package serialport gives garbage output

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

I'm using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport for reading serial data from /dev/ttyUSB0 while running my script i'm getting some data but it's incorrect.

To start. When I'm doing:

> cat /dev/ttyUSB0

I'm receiving the correct data. The data is send with baudrate 19200, 8 data bits, parity: none, stop bits: 1 and flow control: none as described in this PDF: https://www.sv-zanshin.com/r/manuals/victron-ve-direct-protocol.pdf

This command:

> stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0

echo's:

> speed 19200 baud; line = 0; min = 1; time = 0;
> -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
> -opost -onlcr
> -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke

And when 'm using the serialport package with this code:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline')
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/ttyUSB0',{
        baudRate: 19200,
        stopBits: 1,
        parity: 'none',
        dataBits: 8,
        flowControl: false
})


const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }))
parser.on('data', console.log)
```

i'm sometimes receiving 'some' invalid data like:

[image]

While with cat /dev/ttyUSB0 i'm receiving exactly every second the full data block like:

[image]

Does somebody knows what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's what happens when you disable flowControl and it turns out that your app isn't responsive enough to handle the data flow.  The input buffer overflows and you just lose a bunch of stuff.  Typical kick-the-tires problem, console.log isn't what you actually want to do with the data.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand what you mean and I try to pipe to data to a delimiter to break the data into blocks and convert it to string data. I guess I don't know the correct delimiter because the data block is never returned.